# How to fix "Select a file" error in Oracle Apex 19

Tags: javascript, oracle, oracle-apex, readonly

I'm trying to set up a file upload function which has to be "Value Required." So I upload a file in my Database by clicking "Create." After editing something and hitting the button to apply the changes, Apex cannot find the file I selected when I had created it. It gives me the Error I have to select a new File. But it displays the Link where I can download the old file I uploaded previously.

I tried to disable the function with a dynamic action when the Item is null. But it gave the same error.

The second thing I tried was to make it read-only if its null but then I have to get it back to normal if I then want to overwrite the file by uploading a new one.

My expected result is that the file upload automatically selects the file i uploaded previously so it doesn't want me to select a new file.

[The upload page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tVyPl.png),
[The Notification that have to select a new File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FOwyt.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of setting item's "Value Required" property to "Yes", switch to a **validation**.

- type: item is not null
- item: `P1_ITEM_NAME` (whichever it is)
- set server side condition:

  - when button pressed: `CREATE` (so that it fires only when you push the "Create" button)

    - if it turns out that it should fire for some other buttons as well (for example, "Apply changes" (i.e. the "Save" button), then use condition's type "Request is contained in value" and specify all button names (e.g. `CREATE,SAVE`) because - by default - button's request is equal to its name